# NonUniqueObjectException migrating to hilo generator strategy

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a database with existing data, where previously I've been using AUTO_INCREMENT on the db to generate the PK.

To improve performance and facilitate bulk inserts, I'm trying to introduce a different key generation strategy:

```
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
@GenericGenerator(
        name="generator", strategy="hilo")
private Integer id;
```

I've found documentation on the `@GenericGenerator` syntax hard to come by, so I'm not sure if I've implemented it correctly.  As I understand it, this generator generate a PK for the entity PRIOR to performing the INSERT, therefore preventing the need for a post-insert query to discover the pk.

However, it's resulting in a `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException` exception when trying to do an INSERT - presumably because the values hibernate is attempting to use for the PK's are already taken.

Is my understanding here correct, and - if so - how do I configure Hibernate to read the appropriate tables on startup and select the lower PK bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using `tablehilo`. Anyways, the `Generator` code is very important to troubleshoot the thing. So, please provide the relevant snippet.

Furthermore, I strongly suggest you to have a look at [this approach here](https://www.hibernate.org/170.html), if you have not already had.

Comment: There is no other code snipped available (perhaps that's what's wrong).  I took from the docs "strategy is the short name of an Hibernate3 generator strategy" that 'hilo' is a valid string to use there.

I'll look at the approach you've provided - thx.